# Logback: How can i get the log file path?

Tags: java, logback

I'm using Logback in my spring Boot aplication and it's working fine, but i need to get programmatically the absolute path of the file that i'm loggin/writing with the appender's  name "FILE-AUDIT".

To be more clear, given the xml config file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
        <property name="LOG_ROOT" value="/home/sysadmin/logs" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level] - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_ROOT}/audit.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level] - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ROOT}/archived/audit.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                        </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

        <logger name="com.globant.corp.kit" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**I need to write a method that gives me in return "*/home/sysadmin/logs/audit.log*"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could share a properties file between spring and logback. Or you could access `context` scoped logback properties programatically. Or you could dig through your logback context looking for the appender.

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property scope="context" name="abc" value="xyz"/>
</configuration>
```

**java**

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    System.out.println(context.getProperty("abc"));
}
```

Alternatively to import a properties file off the classpath into logback you use:

```
<configuration>
    <property resource="resource1.properties" />
</configuration>
```

Both these solutions mean that you'd have to move `/audit.log` into a property. The properties file solution is likely easier to integrate with spring.

You could possibly get it directly from the appender but you need even more dodgy casts:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger logger = context.getLogger("com.globant.corp.kit");
RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> xyz = (RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>) logger.iteratorForAppenders().next();
TimeBasedRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = (TimeBasedRollingPolicy) xyz.getRollingPolicy();
rollingPolicy.getFileNamePattern();
```