# Get the file path from logback library

Tags: android, logback

I am wondering if there is a way we can get the file path configured to logback for it to save in the specific directory back from the logback library.

For example I wrote a wrapper around logaback and the app is passing the file path and I am just using it to pass it to logback and whenever app or my wrapper wants to know what the path was where the logs are being saved, how would I do get that? (I don't want to persist the path in the app or my wrapper). I want to get the directory or list of file paths which is current and also archived by the rolling appender.

Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229521/logback-how-can-i-get-the-log-file-path) can help.

Comment: Hey Raj, Thanks for the reply. That kinds of solves my problem but not completely. So what I was looking for was to see if logback has capability of retrieving all the paths for individual files (archived and also active). But looks like the above was like me setting the property and then retrieving that property. It would be kind of mess up if I have to handle all that logic of setting the properties manually for the files which are going to be archived and for the active one.